# Keystroke shortcut for File name while saving file

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am wondering what is the shortcut while you save a file, to jump to the file name textbox just like the Alt+D jumps to the path textbox

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDfZu.jpg

Comment: Typically, that field is ready for direct entry after opening this dialog. But the TAB key will also get you there in proper order, one after the folder selection field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows, you can press Alt and then the letter that has an underline in the title of a button or text box to activate that item. In the Save As dialogue, alt-n jumps to the file name box.

Comment: thank you @Scott